# Create an XML-RPC Request with xmlrpc_encode_request

Tags: xml-rpc

I want to generate a request which contain struct as tags. As in `xmlrc_ecode_request` if i pass 2nd variable as any value then "int" tag is generated and if I pass any string "string" tag is generated with value.
I need to generate as shown below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>Request.getName</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                   <member>
                      <name>RequestNumber</name>
                      <value><string>00471627612</string></value>
                      <name>Request2</name>
                      <value><string>471627612</string></value>
                    </member>
                 </struct>
             </value>
         </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

Please help me out to generate the above request.
Thanks,
Sumit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` as params:

```
$method = 'Request.getName';
$params = [
    'RequestNumber' => '00471627612',
    'Request2' => '471627612'
];
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request($method, $params, ['encoding' => 'utf-8']);
print_r($request);
```

But `xmlrpc_encode_request()` not allows to put arrays to the same `member` tag (checked on PHP 5.6.2). So your new structure will be look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>Request.getName</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>RequestNumber</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>00471627612</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>Request2</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>471627612</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate the output this way you simply need to pass an associative array. So this: 
`$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("methodname", array("username", "password", array('first_name'=>'John', 'last_name'=>'Smith')));`

Would output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>methodname</methodName>
<params>
<param>
 <value>
  <string>username</string>
 </value>
</param>
<param>
 <value>
  <string>password</string>
 </value>
</param>
<param>
 <value>
  <struct>
   <member>
    <name>first_name</name>
     <value>
      <string>John</string>
     </value>
    </member>
   <member>
    <name>last_name</name>
    <value>
     <string>Smith</string>
   </value>
    </member>
   </struct>
  </value>
 </param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

Note that the first array is just values, the second is associative (name/value pairs) which creates the structured block. Just add another array to create another block.